# IOS Application Update Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I was wondering if I do an update to my app, will it overwrite the core data database if the user has stuff inside it or will it just keep the database there? I want to make sure that it doesn't delete whatever the user has saved. Do I have to make a copy of it or just leave it alone on the update?

Comment: Generally it will stay there. But you should give some details of where you saved the store file...

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following call (to NSPersistentStoreCoordinator) in your code:

```
addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]
```

If the storeURL in the above call points to the file in Document directory (which it should) then upgrade will not touch your database.